# Issues with signal detending using smoothness priors on the last detended elements

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I tried to use smoothness priors method from neurokit2, to detrend my signal.

https://neurokit2.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/neurokit2/signal/signal_detrend.html

The method was based on the research paper Method by Tarvainen et al., 2002. (Tarvainen, M. P., Ranta-Aho, P. O., & Karjalainen, P. A. (2002). An advanced detrending method with application to HRV analysis. IEEE Transactions on Biomedical Engineering, 49(2), 172-175.)

I also took a look in the paper, and the implemented code looks OK.
So I really need some help on this issue:

```
    def signal_detrend_smoothness_priors(signal, regularization=500):
        
    N = len(signal)
    identity = np.eye(N)
    B = np.dot(np.ones((N - 2, 1)), np.array([[1, -2, 1]]))
    import scipy as sp
    D_2 = sp.sparse.dia_matrix((B.T, [0, 1, 2]), shape=(N - 2, N))
    inv = np.linalg.inv(identity + regularization ** 2 * D_2.T @ D_2)
    z_stat = ((identity - inv)) @ signal

    trend = np.squeeze(np.asarray(signal - z_stat))

    # detrend
    detrended = np.array(signal) - trend
    return detrended
```

The method constantly returns fixed two last parameters, and the signal tapers off towards the end.

End of the original signal:
1107.0, 1068.25, 1029.5, 990.75, 952.0, 939.0, 939.0, 893.0, 903.0, 1004.0, 1172.0, 1101.0, 1040.0, 986.0, 921.0, **963.0, 978.0**]

End of the identified trend through the method:
192.12546294,  173.40315833,  155.18668501,  137.54799278, 120.56268372,  104.30992768,   88.87237529,   74.33606792, 60.79044746,   48.32841445,   37.04619828,   27.04344702, 18.42367655,   11.29498257,    5.76979111,    1.964643  , **963.        ,  978.**        ])

End of the detrended signal through the method:
8.32209553e+02,  8.54671586e+02,  9.66953802e+02,  1.14495655e+03, 1.08257632e+03,  1.02870502e+03,  9.80230209e+02,  9.19035357e+02, **0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00**])

*p.s. I also tested some other code and sometimes these solutions also have issues with the last two elements in the detrended signal.
-2.83746979e+01, -2.66270824e+00,  1.15376970e+02,  3.01091508e+02, 2.47593345e+02,  2.02817006e+02,  1.62618182e+02,  1.07901742e+02, **-8.07242640e+02, -8.06423102e+02**])*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper says a second-order difference matrix  (N-3)x(N-1). To do this you have to do:

```
B = np.dot(np.ones((N, 1)), np.array([[1, -2, 1]]))
D_2 = sp.sparse.dia_matrix((B.T, [0, 1, 2]), shape=(N - 3, N-1))
```

Now the D_2 matrix is ok (N=10, for example):

```
array([[ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The data matrix B for creating the sparse matrix D_2 was created too short (N-2) and it didn't reach the two last columns in the sparse matrix upon creation.

Change the line of code above to this one:

```
B = np.dot(np.ones((N, 1)), np.array([[1, -2, 1]]))
```